# Using ruby mechanize on forms not in <form> tag?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, mechanize

So I'm trying to web scrape a site which has what I would consider a form - several inputs to specialize search such as <select>s and text inputs - that is not within <form> tags.
Rather, they seem to be grouped in <div>s.

The site queries using JavaScript from there, so essentially all I want to do is fill out the 'form' (various inputs) and then hit the submit button and safe the info returned.

However, I can't find a way in mechanize to grab buttons, selects, etc. that aren't in forms. Is there a way?

Comment: You won't be able to use `form_with` to target elements that aren't inside a form, if that's what you're trying... However, since you've shown us neither the HTML nor your code, there's little more advice I can give besides "Yes, there is a way".

Comment: For example, you can locate elements by ID, or by CSS, or by XPath, or within an iFrame, or whatever. But I can't suggest what's possible, let alone what's "best", without knowing anything about the HTML you're targeting

Comment: @TomLord isn't mechanize simply a scraper on top of a HTML parser? If you want to run javascript you would need browser automation (Capybara) instead.

Comment: @TomLord I wish I could share the HTML but cannot, I'm just very confused that mechanize would be so rigid as to only allow this targeting with forms so I guess I'll have to use Nokogiri and xpaths. Thanks for responding!

Comment: @DesPhantomes mechanize is *not* rigid in only allowing the targeting of forms. You can target any element. But if you use the `form_for` method then, by definition, the method only works when targeting a form.

Comment: @TomLord I guess my confusion is that there doesn't seem to be a good way to get the elements commonly found in forms in a different way. For instance, I see no way to get a button from a page unless it's in a form (without using class/ID targeting or xpath). Am I still wrong there?

Comment: @DesPhantomes I cannot pass judgement on there "not being a good way" without seeing an example of the HTML, nor your attempted solution. But yes, you would need to use some other selector. If the element is *not in a form*, then you cannot use a selector that's specifically targeting forms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mechanize cannot work on JS interactive websites.

For web scraping, I would suggest using Kimurai framework. It is built on top of Mechanize.

> Kimurai is a modern web scraping framework written in Ruby which works
> out of box with Headless Chromium/Firefox, PhantomJS, or simple HTTP
> requests and allows to scrape and interact with JavaScript rendered
> websites.

Use any of the [JS engines](https://github.com/vifreefly/kimuraframework#available-engines) available while **scraping**.

You can execute JS which triggers an event to show form and there on you can use capybara helpers to fill in the form and submit

> All the power of Capybara: use methods like click_on, fill_in, select,
> choose, set, go_back, etc. to